# How do I sort by first item of array element?

Tags: python, numpy, sorting

let's assume I have an array of form

```
a = [ 
  [ [12, 4, 2, 5] , [10, 12, 4, 2], [2, 2, 10, 2], [7, 10, 3 ,2] ],
  [ [13, 23, 4, 5] , [10, 12, 4, 2], [2, 2, 12, 1], [7, 10, 3 ,2] ],
  [ [4, 4, 2, 5] , [10, 12, 4, 2], [2, 2, 3, 2], [7, 10, 3 ,2] ], 
]
```

I want to sort by the first column of each element, so the first entry of `a` would read:

```
[ [2, 2, 10, 2], [7, 10, 3 ,2], [10, 12, 4, 2], [12, 4, 2, 5] ]
```

I've found a solution that looks like `a[a[:,1].argsort()]` and tried a for loop over the first index like:

```
for i in range(0,4):
  a[i,...] = a[a[i,0,:].argsort()]
```

or

```
for i in range(0,4):
  a[i,...] = a[i, a[i,0,:].argsort()]
```

This doesn't work tho. I really can't get my head around this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`argsort`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/reference/generated/numpy.argsort.html) of the array indexed along the first columns, and expanding dims appropriately, and then [`np.take_along_axis`](https://numpy.org/devdocs/reference/generated/numpy.take_along_axis.html):

```
ixs = a[...,0].argsort(1)[...,None]
np.take_along_axis(a, ixs, 1)

array([[[ 2,  2, 10,  2],
        [ 7, 10,  3,  2],
        [10, 12,  4,  2],
        [12,  4,  2,  5]],

       [[ 2,  2, 12,  1],
        [ 7, 10,  3,  2],
        [10, 12,  4,  2],
        [13, 23,  4,  5]],

       [[ 2,  2,  3,  2],
        [ 4,  4,  2,  5],
        [ 7, 10,  3,  2],
        [10, 12,  4,  2]]])
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```py
sorted_array = [sorted(x, key=lambda y: y[0]) for x in a]
```

How does this work?

- first we use list comprehension to map the array `a` into a new one, performing an operation on each element (e.g. `[x + 1 for x in my_numbers]`)
- The operation we perform on each element of `a` is to use `sorted`. This returns a copy of an array, sorted by comparing whatever value is returned by `key`.
- `key` must be a function that returns a 'sortable' value. Here, we're using a `lambda` to create a one-line function that returns the first item from the array passed to it. This ensures that we sort based on the first column of each element of `a`.

Comment: This solution didn't let me plot the array with matplot anymore.

Comment: Well, in fairness, you didn't mention you were using matplot ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Answer (score 1):

If you don’t want to use lambda method try this one:

```
def select(item):
  return item[0]


s_array=[]
for i in a:
  s_array.append(sorted(i, key=select))
```